# Scroll two dirreferent viewpagers same time in android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

i need scroll my view pagers same time when scroll one view pager. also those viewpagers has different item width. bottom view pager is full width content and top view pager smaller than bottom view pager item.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener`. The method you could use is the `onPageScrolled` method.

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //Move other viewpager by the same positionOffset
}
```

You can set this listener for both ViewPagers, and by changing one, you can make the same change on the other as well.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530958/scroll-multiple-viewpagers-at-the-same-time-with-a-gesture